# Applying graduated symbol renderer only on some features using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, features, rendering

I have set up a graduate symbol renderer [(QGIS cookbook - Graduated Symbol Renderer)](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#id21), and I am now trying to make it conditionally applied to some features only, depending on one (or more) attributes. For example, only trying to apply the render to features having X value and not display the other ones.

Is [`QgsRuleBasedRenderer`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRuleBasedRenderer.html) to be used, or should I go with creating a virtual layer with only the required features following my requirements?

```
from qgis.PyQt import QtGui

file = 'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/20200123_T00_QGIS.txt'
uri = "file:///" + file + "?delimiter=|%5Ct%7C&skipLines=27&skipEmptyFields=Yes&detectTypes=yes&xField=Longitude&yField=Latitude&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no"

Hsep = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'Hsep', "delimitedtext") 
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(Hsep)
layer = Hsep
targetField = 'H-sep'

rangeList =[]
opacity = 1

# define value ranges
minVal = 0.1
maxVal = 0.3
# range label
lab1 = '0.1 - 0.3'
# color (yellow)
rangeColor = QtGui.QColor('light green')
# create symbol and set properties
symbol1 = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
symbol1.setColor(rangeColor)
symbol1.setOpacity(opacity)
symbol1.symbolLayer(0).setStrokeStyle(Qt.PenStyle(Qt.NoPen))
#create range and append to rangeList
range1 = QgsRendererRange(minVal, maxVal, symbol1, lab1)
rangeList.append(range1)

# define value ranges
minVal = 0.3
maxVal = 0.5
# range label
lab2 = '0.3 / 0.5'
# color (yellow)
rangeColor = QtGui.QColor('red')
# create symbol and set properties
symbol2 = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
symbol2.setColor(rangeColor)
symbol2.setOpacity(opacity)
symbol2.symbolLayer(0).setStrokeStyle(Qt.PenStyle(Qt.NoPen))
#create range and append to rangeList
range2 = QgsRendererRange(minVal, maxVal, symbol2, lab2)
rangeList.append(range2)

# create the renderer
groupRenderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer('', rangeList)
groupRenderer.setMode(QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.EqualInterval)
groupRenderer.setClassAttribute(targetField)
# apply renderer to layer
layer.setRenderer(groupRenderer)

# add to QGIS interface
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```